# Does Selenium WebDriver return incorrect Cookie.Expiry?

Tags: selenium, cookies

I want to test if the authentication cookie is persistent when "RememberMe" is checked in the login page by checking the value of the Cookie.Expiry property. It is a suprise that the Expiry is always null inspite of whether the "RememberMe" value.

I can see a valid expiration date in Chorme/IE's developer tools but selenium Cookie.Expiry is always null.

So I write a unit test to ensure this:

```
    [Test]
    public void Cookie_SHOULE_respect_Expiry()
    {
        const String cookieName = "foo";
        const String cookieValue = "bar";
        DateTime? cookieExpiry = new DateTime(2014, 09, 27);

        Browser.Navigate().GoToUrl(SiteUrl);
        Browser.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();

        var cookieBeforeAdded = Browser.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed(cookieName);
        Assert.IsNull(cookieBeforeAdded);

        Cookie newCookie = new Cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, "127.0.0.1", "/", cookieExpiry);
        Browser.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(newCookie);

        var cookieAfterAdded = Browser.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed(cookieName);
        Assert.IsNotNull(cookieAfterAdded);
        Assert.IsNotNull(cookieAfterAdded.Expiry);  //Failed, the Expiry is null!!
        Assert.IsTrue(cookieAfterAdded.Expiry.HasValue);
        Assert.AreEqual(cookieExpiry.Value, cookieAfterAdded.Expiry.Value);
    }
```

Is it a bug or my mistake? Any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in Selenium marked as WontFix for IE: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3456

I can't find a similar bug for Chrome, but I am seeing the same behavior.